# IntelliJ IDEA why do some js files have different icons?

Tags: intellij-idea

Can someone please explain why some of my JS test files have different icons?

I did search but I can't find an explanation.
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 (Ultimate Edition)

[image]

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html#file-type-icons - `05...` is a test file, but `04...` isn't recognised as such so it's just plain JS.

Comment: I had already looked at that ref in IntelliJ docs, and at the file types in settings, but that only has the basic icon for JS files and no explanation of what I guess is a decoration on one of the two files. I didn't find it in google search of IntelliJ icon decorations either.
Now to figure out how to tell IJ it is a test file.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ detects the file type based on content.  In this case it has detected that 05 is a test file but 04 is not.

I made copies of the files and 04-1 was not recognized as a test, but 05-1 was.  Pasting the content of 05 into 04-1 changed the icon.

Caused by a conditional describe for a mocha test suite

```
let myCondition = (process.env.SMEE === 'something') ? describe : describe.skip;

myCondition('Test Suite Title', async function(done) { ... }
```